# iOS simulator taking 2-3 minutes every-time for starting/invoking

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I have set up appium on mac for iOS automation.

It is taking 2-3 minutes everytime to start the simulator.

Most of the sections they said it will take time only first time but here it is taking time everytime

It was a waste of time to wait so much after every execution.

Few links have said to set `newCommandTimeout` as the capability but that doesn't work.

I am using below version

- appium-desktop-1.2.7-mac
- Xcode 8.1
- Simulator iPhone 7 Plus
- MacOS Sierra Version 10.12

Any workaround will be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Reset Strategies](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies.md)

if you add capability **noReset**=**true**, your simulator will be started only **once**

Comment: Thanks dmle.. Yes I thought may it work .. I am out of office.. I will try tommorrow and let you know regarding same .. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Works as expected .. Thanks