# Starting application in Appium takes too long

Tags: java, android, appium

I've just started an Android automation project and I've been having troubles with running my tests. I start the server and the test, but the time that it takes the test to actually start running is around 2-3 minutes.

I've tried many suggested solutions, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694434/ios-simulator-taking-2-3-minutes-every-time-for-starting-invoking) one, but nothing seems to make it any faster.

**Here are the capabilities I'm using:**

```
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability("no", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 180);
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("avoidProxy", true);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "device");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", appPackage);
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", appActivity);
        capabilities.setCapability("noRest", true);
```

I'm using **Appium 1.7.1** and I'm running tests on a real Android device.
This really bothers me, as I like to try the code that I write, but wasting 2-3 minutes every time to start it is too much. I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You have crazy mix of different capabilities (including duplicates). Try only required ones:

```
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Android);
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "mydevice");
capabilities.setCapability("app", pathToApk);
capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", appActivity);
capabilities.setCapability("appWaitPackage", appPackage);
capabilities.setCapability("androidInstallTimeout", 90000);
```

In addition, to speedup pre-setup on real device *disable device locking*, it may be the reason for Appium stuck on it.

It usually may take a minute or so, if you still see issue -> provide appium server log.

Comment: Tried changing the capabilities, unfortunately, still takes as long. I'll provide the log tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall unused software(ex. Spell checker) from Eclipse Marketplace, sometimes it will speed up the script execution in Eclipse.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmK3i.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following. It will start in less than 15 seconds

```
cap.setCapability("skipDeviceInitialization", true);
cap.setCapability("skipServerInstallation", true);
cap.setCapability("ignoreUnimportantViews", true);
```